# Insert values into MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c

I am trying to insert values into MySQL table using PHP.

PHP code:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "xcode";
$pass = "xcode";
$db = "xcode";
$r = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if (!$r) {
    echo "Could not connect to server\n";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    echo "Connection established\n";
}

echo mysql_get_server_info() . "\n";
$r2 = mysql_select_db($db);

if (!$r2) {
    echo "Cannot select database\n";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
  echo "database selected\n";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO name(name) VALUES('$_POST[name]')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    echo "1 record added";
}
mysql_close();

?>
```

Objective-C code:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.12:81/priya/sample.php?name=%@", txtname.text];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
```

I got database connection successfully, but values are not inserted. Where is the mistake?

Comment: And what error you getting ?

Comment: echo the query, run it in the db environment directly. See what is the error. Also, if this is exact copy of your code, then there should be a space in query near: ..(name)values..

Comment: no error but values are not inserted in sql table

Comment: 2014-02-19 11:26:32.603 sqlapp[755:a0b] Connection established
5.5.34
database selected
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\priya\sample.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
1 record added

Comment: try adding single quotes to 'name' when you're posting it. 

$_POST['name'];

Comment: @remedy.:i got syntax error for  $_POST['name'];

Comment: you should consider moving away from using mysql_connect. http://ca1.php.net/mysql_connect

Comment: Use PDO or mysqli. The old mysql API is deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Your code contains [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) vulnerability. Never pass input directly to the database without sanitizing it!

Comment: @amirtha The error message tells you that you did not set `$_POST['name']`. Did you mean `$_GET['name']`? Or maybe the input field of the form that submits to this script has different name?

Comment: i got answer for this program.

    $sql="insert into name (name) values('{$_GET['name']}')";
 thanks to you all ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is in this line
 Check below line:

$sql="insert into name(name)values('{$_POST['name']}')";

Answer (score 0):

Check out your database table that have any field(column) name "name" and your text field name "name" and database field(column) name have to be same:

$_POST['name'];

Comment: i got empty row insert after every time i run xcode

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
$_POST['name']
```

but inside you're $sql you need to wrap that in brackets

```
$sql="insert into name(name)values('{$_POST['name']}')";
```

But you should also definitely start looking into [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: The originally used syntax also works. See [string manual](http://php.net/language.types.string.php).